# undefined method `path_separator' for Gem:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, jenkins

I am running ruby and rails application via jenkins in passenger/nginx. Application build successfully by Jenkins. but the website is showing the below passenger error.

```
Ruby (Rack) application could not be started.
Error message:
    undefined method `path_separator' for Gem:Module
```

Comment: what is the code that's failing?

Comment: Post the whole error trace.

Comment: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/path_support.rb  67  in `path='
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/path_support.rb  34  in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb  395  in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb  395  in `paths'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb  416  in `path'

Comment: Give me the email Id to send the detailed error screen shot please

Comment: How is this fixed?

Comment: The same is happening to me, 3 years later...

Answer (score 0):

The version of `Gem` being executed is too old to have that method.

You can update with:

```
gem update --system
```

But there may be other issues with running your app on an old version of Ruby like 1.9. Currently, only versions 2.2 and up are supported.

You may want to look into telling Jenkins to use the same version of Ruby that you use in your runtime environment with [RVM](https://rvm.io/) or [Docker](https://www.docker.com/).